# How do I recover my questions from a closed account?

Tags: support

How do I recover the questions I asked before I closed my previous account. I closed my first account which is under the same name on the account I am using now, I noticed that after I closed my first account my questions and answer appear under  user35499. The closed account was under the same username that I now currently used.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get them back. I suggest you ask at [meta.se].

Answer (score 1):

Being incredibly old-fashioned, I keep a log of all links to my questions (and all my answers). This is on my computer, and I also print-out hard-copy stored in a clip-file. Dates are essential, of course. This will be of no use to you for 'lost' questions on your closed file, but I mention it so that you might start afresh, doing that, from now on. This is a "closing-the-stable-door-after-the-horse-has-bolted" answer, yet it might be helpful from now on. I hope so.